# Can't create a Servlet in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to create a servlet in eclipse but when I create the name of the Servlet the **finish** and the **next** button don't show up.

> I searched a lot in slack and I verified that:
>
> - My project is a Dynamic Web Project
> - Dynamic Web Module is checked in my Project Propriety
> - I have followed more than a tutorial and the result is the same

Look at this picture Please:
[image]

Comment: You can create it without wizard. Just create a class and extend it from `HttpServlet`.

Comment: Thank you for your help Sir  :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the *Dynamic Web Module* facet is enabled for your project and try writing the package name when creating a servlet.

---

By the way, you don't need a wizard to create a servlet. Just create a class that extends [`HttpServlet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) and annotate it with [`@WebServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html):

```java
@WebServlet("/hello-world")
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
    ...
}
```

Then override the `doXXX(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)` methods to handle the requests.

Comment: Thank you soooooooooooooooo much, You have saved my day ^_^

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have forgotten to type the package name. For educational purposes it is enough to write there the project name in lowercase - so in your situation it would be just `mywebtest`.

Comment: Thank you So much for your information Sir :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

**Prechecks** (Eclipse Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0) with java 1.8 and Tomcat v8.5)

```
Rt click on the project > Build Path > Configure Build Path > Project Facets
Dynamic Web Module: 3.1 or 3.0
Java: 1.8 or any other version selected
Javascript: 1.0
```

Now try creating servlet (Rt click src/main/java > New > Servlet > Follow usual instructions as shown). If servlet not created, then try following solution

**Solution**

```
Rt click on the project > Build Path > Configure Build Path > 
a.  Java Build Path > Libraries > Remove Apache Tomcat instance, if listed.
b.  Targeted Runtimes > Checkmark Apache Tomcat v8.5
Apply & Close
```

Now again try creating servlet, this time it should work and the servlet will be created.